I'm trying to match full names from two different excel sheets with over 10k rows
Spreadsheet A is the main spreadsheet where all my data is stored - roughly 10k rows
Spreadsheet B is the secondary spreadsheet where data for a specific thing is being stored - roughly 5k rows
Spreadsheet A and Spreadsheet B both have the full name columns on column C, I want to identify all matching full names on Spreadsheet A but am having a difficult time doing so. I tried using this code below:
=VLOOKUP(C16,Sheet1!A15:L3867,3,FALSE)

(Yes the column starts on row 16)
I'm not having any luck and feel like I may be over complicating this. Is VLOOKUP the right approach? Lastly, is there a way to color code all names matched?

You are looking for the value in "C16" (imagine this is "test"), and you are looking for that in the range "A15:L3867", and then you take the third column. This means, if you find the word "test" in cell "B20", you return the value of "D20" (as "B" is seen as the first column, the third one is "D"). Is this really what you want?

With "Sheet A" is Sheet1 and "Sheet B" is Sheet2, to highlight the names in A that are in B, you could try this conditional formatting:

select C16 in A and Conditional Formatting > Classic > Formula
to highlight matches: =ISNUMBER(XMATCH(C16,Sheet2!$C$16:$C5000))
in "Applies to" enter the range: $C16:$C10000
add a rule to ignore blanks: Classic > Format only cell that contain > Blanks > Choose custom format and click Ok without setting any format


in "Applies to" enter the range: $C16:$C10000"


make the rule for blanks the first and check "Stop if TRUE"


Example result:


Vlookup always looks for value in first column and return result from other column. So, yoir formula will fail as it will search on column A in sheet1. Another thisng is, when you drag down the formula, it will change lookup table range so you will not get desired reault. I would recommend to use XLOOKUP() instead. Try-
=XLOOKUP(C16,Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!C:C)

If you still want to use VLOOKUP() then try
=VLOOKUP(C16,Sheet1!C:C,1,0)

Another good option is to use INDEX/MATCH
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(C16,Sheet1!C:C,0))


Add TRIM around the ranges in the XLOOKUP:
=XLOOKUP (B34,TRIM(Sheet2!D14:D17),TRIM(Sheet2!D14:D17),)
The TRIM, removes extra spaces in a string, but leaving 1 only and not more than one, and removes extra spaces to zero spaces at the beginning and end of a string, a few database errors resolved by one formula.
As names can be the same for different customers, or entered many times, you may need to add another bit of data to be sure you have "unique" names. I use COUNTIFS all the time, and doing a COUNTIF first for the range of names (lock the column letters and numbers with "$"), in both databases to see if you only get "1" for each name:
=COUNTIF($B$32:$B$34,B34)
if not you will need a COUNTIFS, to maybe add the postcode (can be isolated with RegEx) to be counted with the name.
